# How to extend the number of Symfit parameters arbitrarily in Python

Tags: python, symfit

I have the following optimization code that is a parameterized by a variable `n`.

```
from symfit import parameters, Eq, Ge, Fit
import numpy as np
n = 3
xdata = np.sort(np.random.choice(range(1, 4*n), n)) # Make fake data
print(xdata)
p1, p2, p3 = parameters('p1, p2, p3')
model = p1*p2*p3
constraints = [
    Eq(xdata[0]*p1+(xdata[1]-xdata[0])*p2+(xdata[2]-xdata[1])*p3, 1),
    Ge(p1, p2),
    Ge(p2, p3),
    Ge(p3, 0)
    ]

fit = Fit(- model, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

I would like to use it for much larger values of `n` but I don't know how to change the lines

```
 p1, p2, p3 = parameters('p1, p2, p3')
 model = p1*p2*p3
```

and the `constraints` to cope with an arbitrarily large `n`.

The code is using the [symfit](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) library. That link shows an example of how `parameters` is used and a link to the documentation.

How can one do this?

Comment: `p1, p2, p3 = parameters('p1, p2, p3')` This line is very obscure to me... Could do a [mcve] that doesn't include those libraries? (It may help you as well as it will help me)

Comment: @UlysseBN The problem is that line is key to my problem. I will add a link to the relevant document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy interacts *really* well with the `symfit` library.  All of the operations you are trying to generalize are fairly trivial when using it.

---

***Setup***

```
n = 3
_data = np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 4 * n), n))
```

---

1. String formatting

   You can dynamically create a `tuple` of parameters using a simple iterator and `str.join`, which you can then pass into the `parameters` constructor to get a `tuple` of your parameters.

```
params = parameters(', '.join(f'p{i}' for i in range(1, n+1)))
                ^^
# p1, p2, p3 = parameters('p1, p2, p3')
```

2. `np.prod`

   This operation is quite straight forward.  [`np.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) computes the:

   > product of array elements over a given axis

   Which when applies to a `tuple` of `symfit` parameters, produces your desired `p1*p2*...pn`

```
model = np.prod(params)
        ^^
# model = p1*p2*p3
```

3. `np.concatenate` + `np.diff`

   Probably the most complicated line to generalize, but still not too hard to understand.  You want to multiply the differences of consecutive elements in the data array by your parameters, and sum the results.  Since the first element will not have a difference with a previous element, you can use `np.concatenate` to add it back in.

```
u = np.concatenate((_data[:1], np.diff(_data)))
c1 = Eq(np.sum(params * u), 1)
              ^^
# Eq(xdata[0]*p1+(xdata[1]-xdata[0])*p2+(xdata[2]-xdata[1])*p3, 1)
```

4. `np.column_stack`

   You want a rolling view of your parameters as constraints: `p1-p2`, `p2-p3`, ...`pn, 0`.  This just stacks a one-off tuple with a zero padded on with the original `tuple` of parameters, then uses a list comprehension to unpack into your `Ge` constructors.

```
ges = [Ge(*group) for group in np.column_stack((params, params[1:] + (0,)))]
```

5. Fit!

   I didn't change anything here!

```
constraints = [c1, *ges]
fit = Fit(- model, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

Comment: Nice use of numpy operations, this is definitely nicer than the other bread-and-butter solutions including mine. However I wish you'd explain a bit more about what you're doing and why it works.

Comment: @Avish updated with a bit more information.  Hopefully most of the operators are familiar to the OP since they are already using `numpy`

Comment: @Anush The string formatting will *definitely* not work, you would need to use `str.format`.  Apart from that, I would just test it, I don't really use symfit, and am using 3.6 to test this code

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution is definitely quite complicated!

Answer (score 3):

The parameters string needs to be computed in a dynamic manner from `n`

```py
paramstr = ', '.join(['p{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n)])
# when n=1, paramstr = 'p1, p2, p3'
```

Use `paramstr` as the argument to `parameters` function.

```py
paramvals = parameters(paramstr)
```

`model` can be refactored by reducing `paramvals` over its product.

```py
from functools import reduce

model = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, paramvals, 1)
```

Now to the interesting bit! The `constraints` can be refactored as:

```py
eqs = xdata[0] * paramvals[0] + sum(
    (xdata[i] - xdata[i-1]) * paramvals[i]
    for i in range(1, n)
)

ges = [
    Ge(paramvals[i-1], paramvals[i])
    for i in range(1, n)
]

ges.append(
    Ge(paramvals[-1], 0)
)

constraints = [
    Eq(eqs, 1),
    *ges
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Symfit, but if you're simply trying to generalize the above code to arbitrary N, then:

- You can arbitrarily generate a string that looks like `"p1, p2, p3"` for arbitrary N, and parse it into a list of parameters:

```py
params_string = ", ".join("p{}".format(i + 1) for i in range(n))
params = parameters(params_string)
```

The notion of parsing a string to get a list of parameters sounds smelly to me, and I'm sure there's a nicer way to programatically declare a bunch of parameters, but this will be as close as possible to what your original code was doing.

EDIT: Looking at the Symfit documentation, it seems like `parameters(s)` is just a shortcut, and you can actually just do:

```py
params = [Parameter("p{}".format(i + 1)) for i in range(n)]
```

which doesn't require you to build your own joined string of all the parameter names just so Symfit can split them back into individual parameter names. This would also allow you to define other properties for your parameters, such as their initial values or their min/max bounds.

- You can generalize the `Eq` constraint:

```py
coeffs = [xdata[0]] + [(xdata[i+1] - xdata[i]) for i in range(n-1)]
eq_constraint = Eq(sum(param * coeff for param, coeff in zip(params, coeffs), 1)
```

Or, as another answer does this, using numpy operations:

```py
coeffs = np.concat(xdata[:1], np.diff(xdata))
eq_constraint = Eq(np.sum(params * coeffs), 1)
```

- You can generalize the `Ge` constraints:

```py
ge_constraints = [Ge(params[i + 1], params[i]) for i in range(n - 1)] + [Ge(params[-1], 0]

constraints = [eq_constraint] + ge_constraints
```

Again this could be done using numpy operations, but I'll leave that to @user3483203's answer.

- You can multiply all the parameters using `reduce`:

```py
model = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, params, 1)
```

Or using `numpy.prod`:

```py
model = np.prod(params)
```

This should be enough to generalize the above to arbitrary N.